# non-linear system of a ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> Let $$y'=A(t)y(t)+b(t,y(t)), \qquad y(0)=y_0$$ and $U:=U_\epsilon(0)$ so that there exists $C\geq 0$ with $\|b(t,y)\|\leq C\|y\|$ for all $y\in U$, $t \in \mathbb R$ and $y^TA(t)y\leq -\lambda \|y\|^2$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$ and a $\lambda>C$. Prove that $y_0\in U \implies y(t) \in U$ for all $t>0$.

---

I tried to show $\|y(t)-0\| = \|y_0 + \int_0^t y'(s)ds\| \leq \dots \leq \epsilon$ but this does not lead to the goal.

Comment: The feedback is sub-linear, so the statements about linearly bounded right sides apply. The negative bound on the quadratic form of $A$ is not really necessary. However it would be nice to know that $A$ and $b$ are continuous.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $y:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a solution of the IVP (as Lutz Lehmann wrote, you need some additional assumptions for existence), and let $\|\cdot\|$ be the Euclid norm. Then we have for $t \ge 0$:  If $y(t) \in U_\varepsilon(0)$ then
$$
\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt} \|y(t)\|^2 = y^T(t) y'(t) =  y^T(t) A(t) y(t)  + y^T(t)b(t,y(t)) =:(\ast)
$$
By Cauchy-Schwarz $|y^T(t)b(t,y(t))| \le \|y(t)\|\|b(t,y(t))\| \le C \|y(t)\|^2$, thus
$$
(\ast) \le -\lambda\|y(t)\|^2 + C \|y(t)\|^2 = (C-\lambda) \|y(t)\|^2 \le 0.
$$
Now assume that this solution which starts at $y_0 \in U_\varepsilon(0)$ is leaving $U_\varepsilon(0)$. Then it hits the boundary of $U_\varepsilon(0)$ somewhere for the first time, that is there is some $t_0 > 0$ such that
$\|y(t_0)\|= \varepsilon$ and $\|y(t)\| < \varepsilon$ $(t \in [0,t_0))$.
Then $\|y\|^2$ hence $ \|y\|$  is weakly decreasing on $[0,t_0)$. Thus $\|y(t_0)\| \le \|y_0\|< \varepsilon$, a contradiction.